# Old administrator password of LDAP still working after it has been changed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ldap, openldap

I have a LDAP server in an Ubuntu machine which I browse using Apache Directory Studio. I just changed the administrator password by going to `cn=admin` and changing `userPassword`. However I noticed that afterwards I am able to authenticate using the old and new password.

[Authentication - Apache Directory Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B09jf.png)

However testing it via the `Password Editor`, the old password verification fails.

[Password Editor - Apache Directory Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdAT9.png)

Is this an LDAP issue?

I have restarted the LDAP server and closed/reopened the Apache Directory Studio several times.

Comment: The passwords are possibly stored in two different attributes. Look for `cmusasl*` and `userPassword` attributes on your `cn=admin` entry and the `olcRootPW` attribute of `olcDatabaseConfig=<your DB>`. Can you include a list of attributes (without values) of those entries?